# Let's Encript SSL Certificate and Azure Traffic Manager

Tags: ssl, iis, azure-virtual-machine, lets-encrypt, azure-traffic-manager

I am trying to use `Azure Traffic Manager` to load balance traffic between a website hosted on an `Azure VM` in 2 different regions (Europe and US).

The `Azure Traffic Manager` is setup happily with the DNS name `mywebsite.trafficmanager.net`

I have 2 end points setup with dns names `mywebsite-uk.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com` and `mywebsite-us.westus.cloudapp.azure.com`

In order to setup a vanity domain I have a `CNAME` record pointing to

```
www.mywebsite.trafficmanager.net
```

When I go to `http://mywebsite.trafficmanager.net` or `www.mydomain.com` I get correctly routed to the closest site.

Unfortunately I am struggling when I try to get `HTTPS / SSL` working. I am attempting to use Let's Encrypt via the Certify SSL Certificate Management tool to issue an SSL certificate to each of the servers however I am getting the following error:

```
Validation of the required challengers did not complete successfully. Please ensure all domains to be referenced in the Certificate can be used to access this site without redirection.
```

I have created bindings in `IIS` for both `mywebsite-uk.mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com`, and an A record for `mywebsite-uk` to the ip of the web server and whenever I request a certificate that includes `www.mydomain.com` I get the error.

Has anyone got an experience with this type of setup? and more importantly any advice on what I am doing wrong? Would I be better biting the bullet and getting a paid for SSL certificate?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: There is no technical reason why you can't use the same SSL certificate for both. But some SSL certificate issuers license them per server.You can try to use different SSL certificate to both server.

Comment: Is your ssl ip based?

Comment: Did you bind ssl to mywebsite-uk.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com and mywebsite-us.westus.cloudapp.azure.com?
If not you need to do that. 
I had same issue, but in my case it was azure webapps.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. The issue does seem to be with the authentication process being used by Let's Encrypt which simply does not support this setup